# Why isn't my controller returning AccessResult::forbidden()?

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

I'm working on a node access module. I've set up my logic. I can't seem to get my code to return AccessResult::forbidden(). I can't even get \dpm to run in access method. What am I doing wrong? Below are my routing.yml and controller.

```
/* nodeaccess.routing.yml */
nodeaccess.people:
  path: '/user/{uid}/edit'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\nodeaccess\Controller\NodeaccessController::content'
    _title: 'Dashboard'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\nodeaccess\Controller\NodeaccessController::access'

/* src/Controller/NodeAccessController.php */

<?php

namespace Drupal\nodeaccess\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult; 
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Defines the Dashboard controller.
 */
class NodeaccessController extends ControllerBase {

 /**
  * Returns content for this controller.
  */
 public function content() {
   $today = date("l");
   if ($today == "Thursday") {
     // Return 403 Access Denied page.  
     \dpm("You are not allowed.");
   }
 }

 /**
  * Checks access for this controller.
  */
 public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
  $current_user = User::load(Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $user = User::load(explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[1]);
  if ($current_user->field_department->target_id != $user->field_department->target_id) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
  return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the user available in the method if you pass it as a parameter, `AccountInterface $account`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually an issue, but in the `nodeacess.routing.yml` file, the `_custom_access` is incorrectly indented. Also, check this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/custom-route-access-checking

Comment: I've made the suggested changes, no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error here `Drupal::currentUser()->id()` should be `\Drupal::currentUser()->id()` and also `explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[2]` gives you only `people` not the user id, to use `User::load`.